# Left and right hand playing same note on piano, or can I ignore it?

Tags: piano, notation

I’m rather new to piano, and I happened to stumble upon this whilst searching up the music score for “Dance for me wallis” by Abel Korzeniowski.

[image]

It appears to be a note, with two tails? Its the top notes on the right hand. I just wanted to know if these were to be played on separate hands, and do I just ignore them? Would really appreciate it if someone could also specify the name of this technique (if any). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret this correctly, the top notes are the melody line, and you are supposed to hold each of them for the length an eight note; additionally, they are part of a pattern of arpeggiated chords played in sixteenth triplets, i.e., three notes evenly distributed in the space of an eighth. You play all of this with your right hand, presumably with the pinky playing the top note, and the other fingers handling the other two notes of each chord; the left hand handles the bass notes on the lower stave.

Answer (score 0):

There are two 'voices'.   Imagine the stems-up melody played by a flute, the broken chords by a harp.  The pianist is being told to emulate that effect.  Very common, and not hard to do.

The left hand also has something that looks technically impossible - how to hold the octave semibreves while playing the notes at the end of the bar? - but which can be faked with the help of the sustain pedal.

Piano music is full of this kind of thing.  The composer shows the required musical effect.  You sort out how to convey it.

Answer (score 0):

The composer what you to know that he got three things going on: A melody, some broken chords beneath it and a bass. Then upright/downright tails indicate the three different "voices" or parts. Think of a three different singers singing the three different parts: Thats the effect you what to achieve. The problem for you as a pianist is that some notes are shared, so you have to do some interpretation here: The melody (top part with upright tails) is usual the most important part, and the composer whats you to bind those notes together as best as you can like a singer singing the melody. The bass is possible to play because you actual got a pause to change chords in beat three. The broken chords has to come third and you what to play them as best you can. Now you would probably what to accentuate the notes where both the melody and broken chords share the same note because you what it to sound like two different singers singing the same note - that is louder and more pronounced.